# I tried to pass the values from one to another page but it doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I want to pass the values from one page to another page my code is:

```
public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "AskMeShowMe2";
private String choice = null;
private String fname = null;
private Menu myMenu = null;
 final static int START =0;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG,"Main - onCreate() ...");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View promptButton = findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    promptButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.greetingsRadioGroup);
    int checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    switch (checkedRadioButton) {
    case R.id.mrButton : 
      choice = "Mr.";
      break;
  case R.id.mrsButton : 
      choice = "Mrs.";
      break;
  case R.id.msButton: 
      choice = "Ms.";
      break;
  case R.id.drButton: 
      choice = "Dr.";
      break;
    }
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.submit_button:
        Intent j = new Intent(this, Info.class);
        j.putExtra("choice", choice); 
        startActivity(j);
        fname=String.valueOf(R.id.firstname);
        Intent t = new Intent(this, Info.class);
        j.putExtra("fname", fname); 
        startActivity(t);

        break;
    }
}
```

and it other Info.Class :

```
public class Info extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Info";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
    Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras(); 
    String choice = b.getString("choice"); 
    String fname = b.getString("fname");

   Log.i(TAG,"selection: " + choice); 
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showmeText); 
   textView.append(": " + choice); 
   TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fname); 
   textView1.append(": " + fname); 

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

when i run this program then my Info.class page doesn't show when i click the submit button,Can you please help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Switch block to following:

```
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.submit_button:
        Intent j = new Intent(this, Info.class);
        j.putExtra("choice", choice); 
        fname=String.valueOf(R.id.firstname);
        j.putExtra("fname", fname); 
        startActivity(j);

        break;
    }
```

As you are starting Activity Info two times, Putting extras to only one intent, which is being started earlier.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Intent j = new Intent(this, Info.class);
j.putExtra("choice", choice); 
fname=String.valueOf(R.id.firstname);
j.putExtra("fname", fname); 
startActivity(j);
```

instead of

```
 Intent j = new Intent(this, Info.class);
    j.putExtra("choice", choice); 
    startActivity(j);
    fname=String.valueOf(R.id.firstname);
    Intent t = new Intent(this, Info.class);
    j.putExtra("fname", fname); 
    startActivity(t);
```

becuase currently you are calling startActivity two times first for `intent j` and second time for `intent t` so remove one and put both choice and fname in single intent and call startActivity only once.